# Raycasting from vertices is not working

Tags: c#, unity

I have two perpendicular planes in xz and yz like this

[image]

I want to find the projection of the vertices of plane 2 on plane 1 using raycasting.The rays are hitting the plane but the log is showing zeros. why?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

//[ExecuteInEditMode()]
public class PlaneManipulation : MonoBehaviour {
    Ray ray;
    RaycastHit hit;

    Mesh mesh;
    private Vector3[] vertices;
    public float rayLength;

    public LayerMask planeLayer;

    void ChangeMesh() {
        mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().sharedMesh;
        vertices = mesh.vertices;
        //using only the first row of the vertices from the plane
        for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
        {
            Vector3 vert = transform.TransformPoint(vertices[i]);

            Physics.Linecast(vert, Vector3.up, out hit,planeLayer);

            Debug.DrawRay(vert, Vector3.up);

            Debug.Log("hitPoint = " + hit.point);

            //vert.y = hit.point.y;
            //vertices[i].y = hit.point.y;
            //vertices[i] = transform.InverseTransformPoint(vert);
        }

        mesh.vertices = vertices;
        mesh.RecalculateNormals();
        mesh.RecalculateBounds();
    }

    void Update() {

        ChangeMesh();
    }
}
```

Comment: i added the same layer for both the planes and it is working. why?

Comment: It's working for me as well OP. Did you make sure that you assigned the correct layers to your planes?

Answer (score 2):

You're not raycasting, you're **linecasting**:

```
Physics.Linecast(vert, Vector3.up, out hit,planeLayer);

             origin | destination | hit info | layer mask
```

The second argument here is the end of the line you want to check along, *not* the direction of the line. So you're checking for an intersection along the line from your vertex to the point (0, 1, 0) in world space - probably not what you intend.

Check the docs on [Linecast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Linecast.html) versus [Raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) to confirm.

I think what you mean to write is:

```
Physics.Raycast (vert, Vector3.up, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, planeLayer);

              origin | direction | hit info | max distance | layer mask
```

I've labelled the arguments here because [implicit conversion between layer masks and numbers makes it easy to accidentally get the wrong override without any errors or warnings](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/109652/39518).