# Raycast not hitting a collider

Tags: unity, physics, mathematics, raycasting

I have the following simple raycast from a capsule on a cube:

```
bool hit = Physics.Raycast
(transform.position, Vector3.down,
jumpSettings.groundJumpDistanceCheck, 
jumpSettings.layerMask);

print(hit);
```

[image]

When my `layerMask` is 8 (terrain), I have set my layer on my cube and my `groundJumpDistanceCheck` is 2. Then my `hit` is ***false***.

When my `groundJumpDistanceCheck` is set to Infinity. Then my `hit` is still ***false***.

However when I remove the distance parameter:

```
bool hit = Physics.Raycast
(transform.position, Vector3.down,
/* jumpSettings.groundJumpDistanceCheck, */ 
jumpSettings.layerMask);

print(hit);
```

Then `hit` returns ***true***. This is odd for me, as far as I know when you exclude the distance parameter it's supposed to be Infinity by default. But when I explicitly give Infinity as the distance, it returns ***false***.

I have also used the following code in an attempt to debug my issue, using the desired distance `2f`

```
Debug.DrawRay(transform.position,
Vector3.down * jumpSettings.groundJumpDistanceCheck, Color.red, 60f);
```

[image]

As you can see, the ray does intercept the cube.

I need the reycast to return true with a distance of `2f`.

Comment: Don't forget to show where you populate your `jumpSettings.layerMask` field - either in the inspector or in code. A common error is to use the layer index as a layer mask, instead of setting the corresponding bit in the mask bitfield, so showing where you provide the value can eliminate this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after doing some more research. I realized that the layermask param was **excluding** layers. This is what it should be:

```
bool hit = Physics.Raycast
(transform.position, Vector3.down,
jumpSettings.groundJumpDistanceCheck, 
1 << jumpSettings.layerMask);

print(hit);
```

Comment: Ah, I see you found that already. :)  As for why you got the confusing result when you removed the distance parameter, [see this previous answer explaining how Unity will silently re-interpret a LayerMask as a max distance](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/109652/39518) if you let it.

Comment: Ah that makes sense, so it was perceiving my `layermask` as the distance. So it was raycasting to any mask within 8 units. Thanks for the link!