# Unity Engine 2D rigidbody inaccurate jumping whilst on a platform that moves downwards

Tags: unity, c#, physics, rigidbody, moving-platforms

I'm currently hard at work on a little platformer in the Unity3D engine, utilizing its 2D capabilities.

Now I have been having a problem where eventhough an object is clearly grounded it somehow doesn't register as such on every frame and thus the jump function, which only runs when the object is grounded, won't work. This so far only seems to happen whilst the player is on a platform that is currently moving downwards.

Now I'm not the best at 2D physics in Unity, so as such I decided to see what everyone here thinks might be the problem.

For illustration purposes here is what it looks like in the editor:

[image]

The white block is the player character, the blue block is the platform (currently moving down) and the red line is a raycast that checks wether or not the player character is grounded.

I hope you guys can figure out what's wrong. All I have so far is that it seems 50/50 wether or not the player is grounded during a frame on the platform, whilst said platform is moving down.

Hereby also my code for the player:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CharacterMovement : MonoBehaviour {

private bool left = false;
private bool right = false;

float velX = 0;
float velY = 0;

[SerializeField]
private float gravity;

[SerializeField]
private float speed;
[SerializeField]
private float maxSpeed;

[SerializeField]
private float jumpForce;
[SerializeField]
private float jumpSpeed;

bool isGrounded = false;
float groundedTime = 0;
float distanceToGround = 0;
float distanceSide = 0;

bool plug = false;
int plugCounter = 0;


void Start () {
    distanceToGround = this.GetComponent<Collider2D>().bounds.extents.y;
    distanceSide = this.GetComponent<Collider2D>().bounds.extents.x;
}

void Update () {

    Grounded();
    WalkingInput();
    Walking();
    Jumping();

    Debug.Log(isGrounded);

    this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(velX, this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);

    //Debug.Log(this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.x + " " + this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity.y);

}

void Grounded()
{
    LayerMask mask = (1 << 8);
    mask = ~mask;
    if (Physics2D.Raycast(new Vector3(this.transform.position.x - distanceSide, this.transform.position.y - distanceToGround - 0.04f, this.transform.position.z),
                          Vector3.right,
                          distanceSide * 2,
                          mask))
    {
        isGrounded = true;
        groundedTime += Time.deltaTime;
    }
    else
    {
        isGrounded = false;
        groundedTime = 0;
    }

    //debugging ray
    Debug.DrawLine(new Vector3(this.transform.position.x - distanceSide, this.transform.position.y - distanceToGround - 0.04f, this.transform.position.z),
                   new Vector3(this.transform.position.x - distanceSide, this.transform.position.y - distanceToGround - 0.04f, this.transform.position.z) + new Vector3(distanceSide * 2, 0, 0),
                   Color.red);

}


void WalkingInput()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Left"))
    {
        left = true;
    }
    if (Input.GetButtonUp("Left"))
    {
        left = false;
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Right"))
    {
        right = true;
    }
    if (Input.GetButtonUp("Right"))
    {
        right = false;
    }
}


void Walking()
{

    if (left == true && velX >= -maxSpeed)
    {
        if(velX > 0)
        {
            velX = 0;
        }

        velX -= speed * Time.deltaTime;

        if (isGrounded)
        {
            if (velX < -maxSpeed)
            {
                velX = -maxSpeed;
            }
        } else
        {
            if (velX < -jumpSpeed)
            {
                velX = -jumpSpeed;
            }
        }
    }
    if (right == true && velX <= maxSpeed)
    {
        if (velX < 0)
        {
            velX = 0;
        }

        velX += speed * Time.deltaTime;

        if (isGrounded)
        {
            if (velX > maxSpeed)
            {
                velX = maxSpeed;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (velX > jumpSpeed)
            {
                velX = jumpSpeed;
            }
        }
    }

    if(left == false && right == false || left == true && right == true)
    {
        velX = 0;
    }

}


void Jumping()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
    {
        Debug.Log("ActuallyJumped");
        this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpForce));
    }

}

}
```

and the code for the platform:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MovingPlatform : MonoBehaviour {

[SerializeField]
Transform pointA;

[SerializeField]
Transform pointB;

[SerializeField]
float platformSpeed;

private float wayThere = 0;

bool going = true; //true = going to b, false = going to a


void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (going == true)
    {
        Vector2 offset = DetermineOffset(pointA.transform.position, pointB.transform.position);
        this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(offset.x * platformSpeed * Time.deltaTime, offset.y * platformSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        if (Vector2.Distance(this.transform.position, pointB.transform.position) < 0.2f)
        {
            going = false;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        Vector2 offset = DetermineOffset(pointB.transform.position, pointA.transform.position);
        this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = new Vector2(offset.x * platformSpeed * Time.deltaTime, offset.y * platformSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        if (Vector2.Distance(this.transform.position, pointA.transform.position) < 0.2f)
        {
            going = true;
        }
    }
}

private Vector2 DetermineOffset(Vector2 PointA, Vector2 PointB)
{

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;

    if(PointB.x > PointA.x)
    {
        x = 1;
    }
    else if (PointB.x < PointA.x)
    {
        x = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        x = 0;
    }

    if(PointB.y > PointA.y)
    {
        y = 1;
    }
    else if (PointB.y < PointA.y)
    {
        y = -1;
    }
    else
    {
        y = 0;
    }

    return (new Vector2(x, y));

}

}
```

Also the editor setups for both the character and the platform in that order:

[image]

All in all I hope one of you good people can help me out on this one and thanks already!

EDIT: Changed the code for the platform to use velocity instead of rigidbody.moveposition. This works better. The bug is now non-existant on low speeds, it is still visible at high speeds. I think it might have to do with how Unity calculates rigidbody gravity because it becomes 0 when a rigidbody is grounded which means that currently the rigidbody is grounded, then it falls, then is grounded, then it falls which would explain the 50/50 ratio as well. I do however find it strange that this would work fine at a lower speed though.

If someone somehow can still manage to find out how to do this at faster speeds I'd be more than happy!

EDIT2: Answered my own question in the end. Check the answers to see how I fixed it.

Comment: Are you trying to model the physics of your player-character with a  Rigidbody? That's very rarely a good idea in a typical platformer.

Comment: There are a number of platformers that do just fine with a Rigidbody for the character, so I don't think that's the root cause of your issue. The way you're raycasting looks unusual though. Typically we'd fire a ray downward, into the collider, intercepting it over a range of distances. Firing the ray sideways means you only see a collision along a very narrow slice - easily missed if your ground platform moves downward under that line. To get a check with some width, maybe you'd want a BoxCast instead?

Comment: @Phillip Loads of people use rigidbody's to model player characters both in 2D and 3D. In Unity this just happens to be the easiest way to get a (mostly) good collisions model for a moving object without writing loads of custom stuff.

Comment: @DMGregory Tried that before. It actually used to be a box, but that had problems back then and I switched to vertical raycasting. That worked for a while until I wanted the character to move up/down a slope or stand on a curved object, I had two raycasts, one each side of the character, pointing perfectly down, but like I said, circular objects it does not like them. Then I started using the horizontal ray you see here both for performance and because it'd actually register along the entire with of the body. I might use a box again cause what it was interfering with has since been scrapped.

Comment: @DMGregory okay so I didn't know that a boxcast was different from a boxcollider, but I decided to google the term just to make sure I wasn't being dense, turned out I was being dense :') currently looking in to what a boxcast could mean for me!

Comment: One other risk to watch out for: moving the platform with MovePosition means the physics engine can't predict where it'll go next, the way it can with velocity. So each fixed step you teleport the stationary platform down in FixedUpdate, leaving a gap that can cause a false negative on the grounded check, until the next velocity step lets the character fall down onto the platform again (and possibly bounce back up, because the physics engine thinks they hit a stationary obstacle) - rather than two bodies falling together in sync with similar downward velocities.

Comment: @DMGregory Oh I thought the whole point of using rigidbody.moveposition was that it would be taken in to account by the physics engine unlike doing it by moving the transform. I'll have to change that then. That might actually be the cause of the problem. Also I have been looking in to boxcast and oh boy am I out of my league. It doesn't seem to work with a mask and so far it is just always colliding with the nearest object to the left of the character. I'm gonna be honest. I got no clue how it works and the documentation isn't helping me much either :')

Comment: It's not fundamentally different than a raycast, and it works just fine with masks - [just watch the order of arguments](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/109652/39518). Feel free to post a more specific question "how do I use BoxCast [to do ABC]" and someone here can step you through the details.

Comment: I know how to use a standard Raycast and spent some time looking at the documentation for the boxcast, but quite honestly I'm failing to see both what it'd add to the project and I'm confused because it asks for a ContactFilter2D however it doesn't accept one, it does accept a mask, but then it seems to entirely ignore it (I was using the same mask I used for my current raycast). Anyways I'll try posting a different question and link back to this one in the hope someone can explain to me exactly where I am supposed to go with this.

Comment: @DMGregory okay so I just checked the documentation again and this is what a boxcast is literally supposed to do according to unity docs: 

"Casts a box against the colliders in the Scene and returns all colliders that are in contact with it.

A BoxCast is conceptually like dragging a box through the scene in a particular direction. Any object making contact with the box can be detected and reported."

I get how it'd work as a wide vertical raycast, but quite frankly I don't think the raycast is the problem here. I'll still try to do an implementation of it, but we'll see

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63203/discussion-between-lakster-and-dmgregory).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright! So I finally figured it out! DmGregory was right and it was a problem with my raycast. However because I couldn't for the life of me figure out how a boxcast is supposed to be done the right way and it didn't quite seem like the type of thing I need, and it's way more expensive on performance than a raycast or a linecast, I decided to switch to the following piece of code in my `Grounding();` function

```
LayerMask mask = (1 << 8);
    mask = ~mask;
    if (Physics2D.Linecast(new Vector2(this.transform.position.x - distanceSide, this.transform.position.y - distanceToGround),
                           new Vector2(this.transform.position.x + distanceSide, this.transform.position.y - distanceToGround - 0.1f),
                           mask))
    {
        isGrounded = true;
        groundedTime += Time.deltaTime;
    }
    else
    {
        isGrounded = false;
        groundedTime = 0;
    }

    //debugging ray
    Debug.DrawLine(new Vector3(this.transform.position.x -distanceSide, this.transform.position.y - distanceToGround, this.transform.position.z),
                   new Vector3(this.transform.position.x + distanceSide, this.transform.position.y - distanceToGround - 0.1f, this.transform.position.z),
                   Color.red);
```

Basically all it is is the raycast is now diagonal. I am gonna add another one that goes at a diagonal the other way (just make sure we covered most corners). Overall thanks for the answers everyone and I hope this'll help someone in the future.

Answer (score -1):

You can try calling the `Grounded()` and `Jumping()` methods from `FixedUpdate()`, because it uses the Physics Engine, with a fixed delta time. Perhaps it happens during the difference between delta time and fixed delta time.

[Read more on Unitys execution order](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html).

Comment: The reason those are in the update is because fixedUpdate doesn't neceserilly run every frame. This makes both the player input in the Jumping(); function inaccurate and the jumping function needs an as accurate as can be grounded function (thus ran as many frames as possible) to give responsive feedback. I might be wrong on the latter part though so I'll try it real quick and report back.

Comment: Yeah no, just tried switching the grounded function to fixed and it does the exact same thing it already did, now it just does it less times per second (as in it calls the function less times per second, not that the problem has decreased)

Comment: FixedUpdate runs with every move of the underlying physics objects, so putting the grounded check there won't miss any movements due to velocity. Checking for jump input in Fixed Update can actually reduce input latency, because you can act on the jump in *this* frame's physics steps (if there are any) instead of queuing them for the next frame's. [You can use a pattern like this](https://twitter.com/D_M_Gregory/status/798804007229587456) to ensure you don't drop inputs when running faster than your physics update rate.

Comment: My bad, you all right, I must first cleary remember this word from unity docs:If the rigidbody has isKinematic set false then it works differently. It works like transform.position=newPosition and teleports the object (rather than a smooth transition).

Comment: That pattern looks more like a work around than a solution for a genuine problem. In the end you are still calling it whenever you press the button to call said function.