# Detecting Player by Raycasting

Tags: unity, c#, raycasting

I am having a problem where my ray is unable to detect the player, even if I did layermask and went to draw ray and all other stuff.

[image: Unity editor screenshot]

Here is my code

```
RaycastHit2D raycastHit2D = Physics2D.Raycast(enemyEyes.transform.position, new Vector2(directionOfRay, 0), LayerMask.GetMask("Player"));

if(raycastHit2D.collider != null )
{
    if (raycastHit2D.collider.gameObject.tag=="Player")
    {
        Debug.Log("Hit Hit");
    }
}

  
Debug.DrawRay(enemyEyes.transform.position,new Vector3(directionOfRay , 0,0)  , Color.red);
```

Problem is HIT HIT is not displaying in console .

Raycasting Problem where my ray is unable to detect my player.

Comment: Remember to use `.CompareTag()` instead of `.tag == ` for better performance.

Answer (score 0):

You've made the same mistake as in this previous question: [Why is Raycast hitting a masked layer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/109605/39518)?

Paraphrasing/quoting my answer there:

> The problem is that raycast functions have so darned many optional parameters, and `LayerMask` isn't picky about what type it's treated as.
>
> [From the docs](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/109605/39518):
>
> ```cs
> public static RaycastHit2D Raycast(
>       Vector2 origin, 
>       Vector2 direction, 
>       float distance = Mathf.Infinity, 
>       int layerMask = DefaultRaycastLayers, 
>       float minDepth = -Mathf.Infinity, 
>       float maxDepth = Mathf.Infinity
> );
> ```
>
> `layerMask` is the fourth parameter. So if you provide only three parameters, Unity wants to interpret them as origin, direction, and **distance**.
>
> It might seem like providing an input of type `LayerMask` should make your intent unambiguous, or at least generate a compile-time error, but `LayerMask` can implicitly convert to `int`, and `int` can implicitly convert to `float`.
>
> So when you put a LayerMask in the third argument, the compiler tries to convert it to a float, succeeds, and so silently re-interprets your mask as a distance.

If your mask evaluates to a small number, like say 1, then you get a very short ray that misses your player. If it evaluates to a large number, you might get a ray long enough to hit the player, but along the way it hits something on a non-player layer (since the function thinks you provided no layer mask), and returns that instead.

> You can fix this by providing a dummy distance value (say, infinity, if you don't have any more conservative upper bound) so your layer mask selections end up in the fourth argument where Unity expects it:

```
RaycastHit2D raycastHit2D = Physics2D.Raycast(enemyEyes.transform.position, new Vector2(directionOfRay, 0), float.positiveInfinity, LayerMask.GetMask("Player"));
```